# Does DD-WRT improve reliability?

Tags: router, wireless-router, dd-wrt, firmware

I recently bought a Netgear WNDR3400v1 router, and have been having reliability issues (devices constantly being disconnected and reconnected).

My router *is* supported for [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices#Netgear).  I understand that DD-WRT adds a lot of high end options and configurability, but I wouldn't know how to use advanced settings anyway - I just need a router that is reliable.

So my question is, would installing installing DD-WRT improve reliability out of the box, or does it just make my router more configurable?

Comment: I had a Linksys E2500 wireless router that would seemingly randomly drop internet connection, mostly under high load. I had dd-wrt on it and for the next few months and never experienced that problem. I don't know a definite answer to your question, but it's helped me with reliability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I flashed a WRT160N to DD-WRT several years ago.  Before I did it, I had to reboot the router about once every 4 days.  I even found a Linux script online that could do it automatically from a cron job.

After flashing it, it pretty much continues working unless I unplug it.

Comment: Mine has issues working when I unplug it too :(

Comment: Same experience here.  Keep in mind the DD-wrt code is revved more often and has more eyes on it than the linksys code so issue may be more likely fixed sooner. YMMV